# Why would evolution favor blue as a color in bugs?

Tags: evolution

This question arose when I saw a metallic blue - black bug some while ago. I can't remember the species name now, but a quick google search will show that such bugs do exist. I'm down with green and black - camouflage, right? But what is the case for blue color? What kind of an advantage does it provide so that they have survived to this date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similarly, you could ask

- Why are bees yellow?
- Why are some frogs so colourful?
- Why widowbirds have such long tails?
- Why do peacocks have such a tail?

There are a number of reasons why such traits could evolve. The main reasons are:

- [Sexual selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_selection) (esp. intra-sexual selection when it comes to colors)
- [Mimicry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimicry) (esp. [batesian mimicry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batesian_mimicry))
- [Aposematism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aposematism)

I let you investigate further by yourself through reading the linked wikipedia articles.

For the specific beetle, you have seen, it will be impossible to address the question unless we know the species.

Comment: Also consider that insects (and their predators) often see different parts of the spectrum than humans do.